# Should I upvote all comments of a person who solved the problem but didn't write a "formal" answer

Tags: discussion

Should I upvote all comments of a person who solved the problem but didn't write a "formal" answer? Or is it an abuse of the system? I want to show my gratitude but the person didn't write an answer...

What should I do in such situation?

Comment: Upvoting comments only adds visibility. It doesn't grant any rep points (the way upvoting an answer does).

Comment: Would that be mafso [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780378/cant-write-to-a-file-when-running-my-code-optimized)?

Comment: @JonEgerton Yup.

Answer (score 6):

The most important is to think about readers. If there are too many comments, and your benefactor seems to not be disposed to answer, you could combine all comments and answer your own question, crediting the guy. As mentioned by [Jon Egerton](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265823/should-i-upvote-all-comments-of-a-person-who-solved-the-problem-but-didnt-write#comment62349_265824), it would of course be better to encourage the guy to answer himself, you would then be able to show your gratitude.

This will allow future visitors to see your question as answered, and quickly see the answer (they don't really care of *who* answered).

If (finally) your guy post an answer, you still can upvote and mark it as the 'new' accepted answer.

And if you want, yes, you still can upvote every comment. This won't act on reputation or anything else.

Comment: He can also comment at the commenter that the comments helped, and encourage to write as the answer themselves so that appreciation can be given.

Comment: @zessx So upvote only the most useful comments. Got it, thanks.